# Terrible access database issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a terrible database from a client and I need to count the number of results from a query, which is as follows:

```
SELECT
  Offices.OfficeID
, ContractsBooksCommodities.CommodityID
  FROM ((((Offices
INNER JOIN tbl_Sales
        ON Offices.CompanyID = tbl_Sales.CompanyID)
INNER JOIN ContractBooks
        ON tbl_Sales.CompanyID = ContractBooks.CompanyID)
INNER JOIN ContractsBooksAds
        ON ContractBooks.ContractNum = ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum)
INNER JOIN ContractsBooksBrands
        ON ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum = ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum)
INNER JOIN ContractsBooksCommodities
        ON ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum = ContractsBooksCommodities.ContractNum;
```

How can I make this count the number of records returned?

Answer (score 3):

In general,

```
select count(*)
from (
  your-select-query
)
```

will give you the number of records returned by your query.

Answer (score 0):

COUNT and GROUP BY would be my guess:

```
SELECT Offices.OfficeID, ContractsBooksCommodities.CommodityID, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM ((((Offices INNER JOIN tbl_Sales ON Offices.CompanyID = tbl_Sales.CompanyID) INNER JOIN ContractBooks ON tbl_Sales.CompanyID = ContractBooks.CompanyID) INNER JOIN ContractsBooksAds ON ContractBooks.ContractNum = ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum) INNER JOIN ContractsBooksBrands ON ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum = ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum) INNER JOIN ContractsBooksCommodities ON ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum = ContractsBooksCommodities.ContractNum
GROUP BY Offices.OfficeID, ContractsBooksCommodities.CommodityID
ORDER BY Offices.OfficeID, ContractsBooksCommodities.CommodityID
```

Comment: If you're not able to get the COUNT query to work for whatever reason you could try just running the query and then using the RecordCount property on the Recordset object (note that you may have to call MoveLast first). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208624%28v=office.12%29.aspx